# Spring AMQP: intercept every incoming and outgoing message

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp

Is there a way to intercept every incoming and outgoing message using spring Spring AMQP? Something like filter in servlet context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring AMQP has an interface `MessagePostProcessor`; the listener container (`SimpleMessageListenerContainer`) can be configured with one or more `afterReceivePostProcessors` which could be used to capture (or manipulate) the message.

Similarly, the `RabbitTemplate` has `beforePublishPostProcessors` and `afterReceivePostProcessors`.

We use this mechanism for compression, for example (zip outbound unzip inbound).